# How to create a new group of radio button in Excel without interference?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-office-2007, forms

**Status:**
I have a form with sections on the same page, in each section the user can only chose one solution. I'm using group of radio buttons on Excel 2007.

**Problem:**
When I ad a new group, the buttons interact with the group a head. I can't make it work separately one from the other, event if the groups have other names.

**Question:**
Can you please help me find an **easy** way  to do that on Excel 2007 (I don't have the choice of the software)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make them independent you need to use the [Group Box form control](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-a-group-box-or-frame-control-to-a-worksheet-HP010236679.aspx).  Surround each group of buttons in a group box control will make them not interfere with each other.

Comment: I used those groups, but they still interact as one same entity.

Comment: There's two different types of radio buttons, make sure you're using the Form Control and not the ActiveX control.

Comment: I'm using the Form Control.